# WPF desktop application open local file e.x. (.doc,.pptx,pdf,.xls)

Tags: c#

Smart people in the world. Anyone knows.. Can WPF desktop application manages to open a local file in its default open software. To give an example, when i clicks a .doc file in my WPF desktop application, Microsoft Word should open such a file

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`Process.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_) and pass the file name. This has nothing to do with WPF.